# MySQL Performance - LEFT JOIN / HAVING vs Sub Query

Tags: mysql, drupal

Which of the following queries style is better for performance?

Basically, I'm returning many related  records into one row with GROUP_CONCAT and I need to filter by another join on the GROUP_CONCAT value, and I will need to add many more either joins/group_concats/havings or sub queries in order to filter by more related values.  I saw that, officially, LEFT JOIN  was faster, but I wonder if the GROUP_CONCAT and HAVING through that off.

(This is a very simplified example, the actual data has many more attributes and it's reading from a Drupal MySQL architecture)

Thanks!

```
Main Records
+----+-----------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | other_record_id | value          | type      | attribute |
+----+-----------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |               0 | Red Building   | building  |           |
|  2 |               1 | ACME Plumbing  | attribute | company   |
|  3 |               1 | east_side      | attribute | location  |
|  4 |               0 | Green Building | building  |           |
|  5 |               4 | AJAX Heating   | attribute | company   |
|  6 |               4 | west_side      | attribute | location  |
|  7 |               0 | Blue Building  | building  |           |
|  8 |               7 | ZZZ Mattresses | attribute | company   |
|  9 |               7 | south_side     | attribute | location  |
+----+-----------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+

location_transaltions
+-------------+------------+
| location_id | value      |
+-------------+------------+
|           1 | east_side  |
|           2 | west_side  |
|           3 | south_side |
+-------------+------------+

locations
+----+--------------------+
| id | name               |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | Arts District      |
|  2 | Warehouse District |
|  3 | Suburb             |
+----+--------------------+
```

Query #1

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        IF(b.attribute = 'company', b.value, NULL)
    ) AS company_value,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        IF(b.attribute = 'location', b.value, NULL)
    ) AS location_value,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        IF(b.attribute = 'location', lt.location_id, NULL)
    ) AS location_id    
FROM 
records a
LEFT JOIN records b ON b.other_record_id = a.id AND b.type = 'attribute'
LEFT JOIN location_translations lt ON lt.value = b.value
WHERE a.type = 'building'
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING location_id = 2
```

Query #2

```
SELECT temp.* FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            IF(b.attribute = 'company', b.value, NULL)
        ) AS company_value,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            IF(b.attribute = 'location', b.value, NULL)
        ) AS location_value
    FROM 
    records a
    LEFT JOIN records b ON b.other_record_id = a.id AND b.type = 'attribute'
    WHERE a.type = 'building'
    GROUP BY a.id
) as temp
LEFT JOIN location_translations lt ON lt.value = temp.location_value
WHERE location_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JOIN is preferable in most cases, because it helps optimizer to understand which indexes he can to use. In your case, query #1 looks good enough.
Of course, it works only if tables has indexes. Check table `records` has indexes on `id`, `other_record_id`, `value` and `type` columns, table `location_translations` on `value`